# "Quick find" for an SWT Table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a table that displays the output from a database, this can often be up to or over 10,000 rows. I'm looking to implement a 'quick find' function that will allow the user to easily scroll to a row with the value for which they search.

The idea is for this to be very similar to Chrome or Firefox's quick find. So:

1. User hits 'CTRL+F'
2. A box pops up:
3. [image: quick find example]
4. The user can then quickly skim through the table pushing / or /\ to each matching value

My question is, does such a table already exist? I have looked at [NatTable](http://nattable.org/drupal/) and [XViewer](http://www.eclipse.org/osee/xviewer/) but they both seem like rather large additions for a relatively minor change.

Another library I've looked at that is close to fitting the billl is [Lucene TableSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/contrib-swing/org/apache/lucene/swing/models/TableSearcher.html#search(java.lang.String)) unfortunately this is designed for filtering rather than highlighting. However it may be an avenue worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I chose wasn't as simple as I'd hoped but has a satisfactory performance.

The tables involved are virtual tables that can be very large. So on top of this upon loading the dataset we start a thread to build an index in the form of a list. Because these tables can be very large (but aren't often) we set a 50mb limit to this list and stop indexing it when we hit it. For most cases this is perfectly acceptable but for the larger tables it means that whilst it may be slower, it is considerably more stable than other options.

The 'search' is a simple SWT textbox with ModifyListener that iterates over the list, performing a 'contains' on each entry. Upon a match the row and column are calculated from the index number (0=0,0, 1=0,1 ..).

It would have been nice to have a simple 'drop in' solution for this but all of the tables on offer had too many features.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite the same, but JFace does have support for filtering views. You type in a text box and view contents shrink to what matches the filter. It's basically another way to present search/find functionality to the user.

You can see this in action in Eclipse Preferences (the filter text field about the navigation tree in the dialog). See org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree class. I don't believe there is a FilteredTable or equivalent, but underlying facilities are pretty generic, so it shouldn't take much work to put one together. Take a look at FilteredTree source and go from there.

Comment: Thanks, there is already a filter for this table (uses database queries to do the filtering). The idea is that the search will compliment the filter by allowing users to skim through the filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

Use FilteredItemsSelectionDialog dialog box

Comment: Where to find it? Is it part of SWT or JFace?